# How to remove the old IP when transferring the server to the new Host?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, ping

When transferring an old server to a new host, the new Ispmanager gives the old Ip when pinging my sites. How to change?

Comment: Did you update your DNS records? If no, you need to update them.

Comment: I am update DNS. Вut it didnt work...

Comment: What is "Ispmanager" ?

Comment: It sounds like you made a DNS change and you haven't seen its effect.  The DNS record's TTL will specify the maximum time the record _should_ be cached, but each user's recursive DNS provider (usually their ISP) will have to accurately respect the TTL - and it will need to be reached on any cached entry - for the new record to propagate.  Some ISPs fail to respect TTLs very well.  In the mean time, proxying traffic from old host to new might be a good way to keep the site working during the TTL window.

Comment: I update my DNS (knowlege.pro), received Nameservers, my friend advised me to add the old DNS 1stlfs.com to the domain registrar, but 1stlfs still responds ... And in the ISP panel hostname said to write static.116.73.217.95.clients.your-server.de, since the registrar names is on Hetzner, is everything correct?

Comment: ISPmanager software - a commercial web hosting control panel allows you to manage software such as a web server (Apache / Nginx), a database server (MySQL / PostgreSQL), a mail server (Sendmail / Exim / Postfix) and other related programs via the web -interface.